# Run a same script with a same file multiple times

Tags: linux, bash, time, copying

I have an audio file, and I am running a script to decode that audio file. Now I want to measure the latency of the system.
So, I am running a script with a `time` command.
like `$ time ./script.sh`
In the script `script.sh` the file path to the audio file has been mentioned.
Now I want to check, the latency when there will be the same audio file 100,1000 and 10000 times. Initially, I am thinking about actually copying the same audio file 100,1000,10000 times and run the script again to measure time.

Is there any other method, in which I should not copy the same audio file multiple times (like 100 to 10000 times) and measure the time.

Comment: Why do you need to copy the file? I thought you want to measure the latency of decoding it not copying it

Comment: Is the audio file modified after running the script? If it is not, you can just run the same decoding every time. Write something similar to `for i in {1..1000}; do ./script.sh ; done` in script2.sh and use `time ./script2.sh`

Comment: Yes latency of decoding. Not the copying. I  want to check the latency when I will have the same audio file 100 times (means 100 files) @NirAlfasi

Comment: Run the same script once and throw away the results; that will cache the file in whatever OS strata is there, and everything else should run with a level playing field.

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes NO audio file is not modified after running a script. it is a same audio file copied 100 or 1000 times.  I will try the way you have suggested.